How to use \Gamma function
I want to use \Gamma function over a quantity in \Gamma(x+y+z), but the symbol seems shorter and doesn't extend over whole bracket. Can you suggest what can be done?

Please extend or edit your question putting your tex code because it is generic. Thank you.

Please be more specific regarding the cause of why you don't like the "look" of \Gamma(x+y+z). In particular, do please elaborate on what you mean by "the symbol ... doesn't extend over the whole bracket". What bracket are you talking about?

Does g(x) have problems? I don't think so. Neither has \Gamma(x). Perentheses are commonly taller than uppercase letters.

\Gamma is just a letter like ABC it doesn't extend depending on the size of other items.

If you want the size (and behavior) to be similar to that of the product, you'll have to modify the size yourself.  This question might be helpful: How to create my own math operator with limits?

Gamma isn't a "symbol" it's just a normal letter, the third letter in the Greek alphabet just as C is in the Latin. So it would not normally be stretched based on the size of surrounding items, and typically ( ) are slightly larger than capital letters.

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$ \Gamma(x+y+z) + C(x+y+z) $
\end{document}

